# Former2 - missing Tags in Subnets (Troposphere, Raw)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using Former2, I noticed some subnets are not created with their associated tags, I checked this with Troposphere and Raw:

```
EC2Subnet20 = template.add_resource(ec2.Subnet(
    'EC2Subnet20',
    AvailabilityZone=GetAtt(EC2Instance2, 'AvailabilityZone'),
    CidrBlock="30.0.2.0/24",
    VpcId=Ref(EC2VPC),
    MapPublicIpOnLaunch=False
))

EC2Subnet21 = template.add_resource(ec2.Subnet(
    'EC2Subnet21',
    AvailabilityZone=GetAtt(EC2Instance, 'AvailabilityZone'),
    CidrBlock="30.0.21.0/24",
    VpcId=Ref(EC2VPC),
    MapPublicIpOnLaunch=False,
    Tags=[
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "TS-Subnet-Private-Dev"
        }
    ]
))
```

I have manually checked AWS/VPC/Subnets and ther relevant entry for EC2Subnet20 does have 2x Tags.

Comment: Try running the scan again and waiting a little bit longer? Sometimes the table comes back as ready, even though there's still extra scans occurring in the background.

Also, any tag prefixed with `aws:` will not be counted (as it's set by AWS, not the user).

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I left it go for 10 minutes (did this twice) and still no Tags data for most of the Subnets.  I also just Selected VPC/Subnets and same challenge.

Comment: Very strange. If you can find any commonality between those subnets that do have tags and those that don't, that'd be helpful.